# Vue.js render multiple slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following app:

```
<template>
    <component :is="layout">
        <router-view :layout.sync="layout"/>
    </component>
</template>

<script>
    import LayoutBlank from './LayoutBlank'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                layout: LayoutBlank,
            };
        },
    }
</script>
```

```
<script>
    import LayoutBlankTemplate from './LayoutBlankTemplate'

    export default {
        name: 'LayoutBlank',
        created() {
            this.$parent.$emit('update:layout', LayoutBlankTemplate);
        },
        render() {
            return this.$slots.default[0];
        },
    }
</script>
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'LayoutBlankTemplate',
    }
</script>
```

```
<template>
    <layout-blank>
        Test content
    </layout-blank>
</template>

<script>
    import LayoutBlank from './LayoutBlank';
    export default {
        name: 'BlankTest',
        components: {LayoutBlank},
    }
</script>
```

All works fine. But now I would like to add one more slot to the LayoutBlankTemplate:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
        <slot name="second"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'LayoutBlankTemplate',
    }
</script>
```

and use it in BlankTest:

```
<template>
    <layout-blank>
        <template #default>Test content</template>
        <template #second>Second test content</template>
    </layout-blank>
</template>

<script>
    import LayoutBlank from './LayoutBlank';
    export default {
        name: 'BlankTest',
        components: {LayoutBlank},
    }
</script>
```

The code renders only the default slot content. The problem is that I'm using the `return this.$slots.default[0];` in LayoutBlank component which renders only the default slot content.

I cannot find the way how to render all slots in LayoutBlank::render() method. I know that I'm able to get the slots list using this.$slots or this.$scopedSlots but I can't find the way how to pass them to the LayoutBlankTemplate to make them render.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the slots into elements you create I believe.  This is mentioned (briefly) in the render function [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).

This may not be exactly the layout you want, but for example,

```
<script>
import LayoutBlankTemplate from './LayoutBlankTemplate'

export default {
  name: 'LayoutBlank',
  created() {
    this.$parent.$emit('update:layout', LayoutBlankTemplate);
  },
  render(createElement, context) {
    return createElement('div', {}, [
      createElement('div', {}, this.$slots.default),
      createElement('div', {}, this.$slots.second)
    ])
  },
}
</script>
```